# Combined digital signature for checking if majority of signed elements are not changed

Tags: security, digital-signature

I'm not familiar with the field, so please excuse me if the question seems trivial or dull.

I have N strings which I need to sign in such a way, that the signature remains valid if
up to M strings are changed, removed, or added. N > M, N may vary. The signature should not allow for deducing N from the signature itself.

All I can imagine so far, is a strightforward approach with building hashes for each string separately, and storing them all as signature, but it does not comply with the latest requirement.

If there exist some language specific examples, please mention them as well, - Java, C++, PHP, etc. are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation of the matter I found the following information which might be helpful.

There is a so called "[Rolling hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash)". And another closely related technology has the name "Context Triggered Piecewise Hashes" (CTPH). There is a comprehensible article on CTPH:
[Identifying almost identical files using context triggered piecewise hashing](http://dfrws.org/2006/proceedings/12-Kornblum.pdf).

I assume it can be used for signing N elements, concatenated in a single input file.

The algorithm supposes that block size (used for periodical splicing of signatures built from traditional hashes for pieces) is publicly known as it's embedded into the final signature. This could possibly allow deducing approximate size of a signed content, but apparently keeps N in secret.

For a given unknown content the algoritm provides a measure of similarity or **homology**, in terms of CTPH, as a value between 0 (difference) and 100 (identity) between a known signed content and the unknown content using their signatures.